# "Restore-SQLdatabase" Login failed for NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Tags: sql-server-2012, powershell-2.0, database-backups, database-restore

I have a powershell script for DB backup/restore. For some reason I am executing the script remotely using `new-pssession` and `invoke-command`. I am

```
1.connecting to remote server
2.the local server is in a domain
3.the remote server is in same domain
4.Using the domain account which exist in both the machine and have admin rights.
5.My SQL Service (I mean the instance/engine) is running with 
  the same Domain account
```

backup with command `Backup-SQLdatabase` succeeds but restore `Restore-SQLdatabase` failes 
with error `Login failed for NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON`.

Just for trial/error I added "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" to admin group in the machine where restore have to happen but no luck.

Any clue what I am doing wrong (OR) how can I solve this problem.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** will the `-SQLTrustedConnection` switch can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bit I found a trick.   The machine where restore have to happen I added "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" as a user.

How to add:

connect to the DB instance using SSMS -> expand security -> expand login -> right click on login -> create new login